# Установка DBSqlite Browser в Ubuntu

Tags: база-данных, ubuntu, sqlite3

Инструкцию для установки взял здесь https://ubunlog.com/ru/sqlite-3-y-sqlitebrowser-como-instalarlos-en-ubuntu/.
После установки ввожу в терминал команду для открытия: "sqlitebrowser" и вылетает следующее:
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display                                                                                                                                                                           qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.                                                                                                                         This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Целостного решения проблемы найти не получилось. Различные советы вроде sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0  не помогли

Comment: Ну а из официального ppa пробовал? Тоже не поехало? А snap пробовал? Не поехало? А appimage пробовал? Не поехало?